# How send secure data from android to webservice (not using SSL)

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, security

I am a native Spanish speaker.  Please excuse any mistakes with my English usage.

I want to POST data from android to a PHP web service using HTTP.

Should I use `URLEncode` ? Is it secure?

I need to send and receive data `HttpURLConnection`. I hav eread a lot of information on this topic, but I do not understand.  What action must be taken when the connection status is not 200?

Finally, how do I send an `arrayList` to the web service?

Comment: *should I use "URLEncode"? Is it secure?* **Maybe** and **no**.

Comment: How to add security?

Comment: By using SSL. I suppose technically by using [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). That is `https` (not `http`).

Comment: I understand, very thanks! :)

Comment: But, one more question, What action must be taken when the connection status is different than 200?

Comment: Which [Status Codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)?